# Java Spring workflow

Tags: java, spring

I've been working with Rails, PHP and Node.js and used to auto reloading after code changes.

Now I'm trying Java and came to two commands:

```
gradle build --continuous
gradle bootRun
```

But I see changes only after I restart gradle bootRun

Is it possible to rebuild and rerun spring after each code change?

Comment: Are you using just Spring on its own, or as part of Spring Boot?

Comment: If you're using an IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ) then it will take care of that for you in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Spring developer tools will handle this for you. Just add following dependency in your Gradle build file.

```
configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}
dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

For more details refer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html